# Mercurial: Merging with uncommitted changes?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to learn the merging and conflict-resolution workflow in mercurial. Am I supposed to commit any uncomitted changes in my working directory before I merge with another changeset?

What would happen if I merge before committing changes in my working directory?

Comment: Look at the [corresponding FAQ chapter](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.Why_won.27t_Mercurial_let_me_merge_when_I_have_uncommitted_changes.3F).

Comment: With Mercurial you can easily create a test repository, or a test clone of an existing repository to just try these kind of things out yourself. This is a big advantage over e.g. SVN, and I would recommend doing that a lot while learning the ins and outs of Mercurial.

Answer (score 5):

Merging with uncommitted changes is a fundamentally unsound action.  A merge can go wrong and when it does you want to be able to revert to your previous state, which is only possible if those changes are committed.  If you can't bear to create a new changeset at that time commit them into a Mercurial Queue.

Comment: Thanks @Ry4an. I didn't know about Mercurial queues.

Comment: @Ry4an: merge aborts with a dirty working copy. However, update lets you proceed and there you can revert back to the old state with `hg resolve --tool internal:local`. You'll have to do an additional `hg update` afterwards, but we do make backups of dirty files in the working copy.

Comment: @intrpc: if you’re a newbie to Mercurial, I would recommend to stay far away from MQ though. It’s not the easiest to understand, and it can relatively easily mess up your repository or lose your changes if you don’t know what you’re doing.

Comment: It is not always unsound - in fact *not* being able to do that can be unsound. For example, I could have local platform-specific changes to a config file that I will never commit. This is a very common situation. If I have to jump through a lot of hoops like committing to a queue or shelving, there is much more chance of mistakes. For many other commands, there is a way to exclude certain files; It is very annoying that you cannot do that here.